# Why is this code throwing 'google not defined' error and also 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlacesService' of undefined at initialize' - error?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to have a google map api with markers showing nearby restaurants/cafes.
I keep getting the following 2 errors:

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at index.html:47
2. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlacesService' of undefined at initialize (index.html:26) at js?key=[API key]&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly:142 at js?key=[API key]&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly:142

Why am I getting this error and how can I make it work?

```css
html, body, #map{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API KEY=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly"></script>

    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.349804, -6.260310);
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: center,
                zoom: 12,

            });
             var request = {
                 location: center,
                 radius: 8047,
                 types: ['cafe']
             };
              
             var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
             service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
            }

            function callback(results, status) {
                if(status == google.maps.places.PlaceServiceStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i =0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        createMarker(results[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            function createMarker(place) {
                var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
                var marker = new google.mpas.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                });
            }


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="map">
    </div>

            
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `google` is defined in a script file which is not loaded yet at the time you're trying to refer it.

Comment: Why do you have `initialize` both in the JS API callback **and** in the window load listener?

Comment: Please remove the API key from the code snippets. You should never publicly disclose API keys

Comment: Needs to be removed from the Error stacktrace youve provided as well

Comment: @Teemu, but how can I do the reverse and load it first?

Comment: Either remove the async and defer attributes from the `maps.googleapis.com/maps` script tag, or do as Aditya has explained in their answer.

Comment: To add to the explanation provided by @Teemu. By removing `async` and `defer` attributes from the script tag, you are instructing the browser to halt everything it is doing until it has fetched the file and parsed it. This will block your HTML rendering as well. In most cases that would be very undesirable. If at all you remove those attributes, make sure you shift your script tags to the bottom of the body tag so as not to block the rendering of the HTML. The downside to this is that the request to fetch the file from maps will only happen after the HTML has been parsed.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestions and explanation.

Comment: Whoever edited the question and removed `&callback` from the script src should add it back and again, as per my first command, you should **NOT** call your `initialize` function in 2 places...

Comment: @AdityaMenon JS API keys are by default public and visible on any website using the API. You need to restrict your API keys though.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I get what you mean about it being called in 2 places, however when I get rid of the DOM listener event calling initialize on load, my map doesn't even appear and I get an error saying 'initialize is not a function'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that your inline script is firing immedietly as its parsed. At that point the script you need from maps has not loaded yet. Infact it will only load once the rest of the page has been parsed.

To fix this, shift your inline code into a `.js` file and load it like you are the maps file, in a `script` tag with a `src` pointing to your file and a `defer` attribute. Ensure the script tag for this comes after the request for the maps file

Comment: Thank you Aditya, that solved the google error, now I only have the 'PlacesService' error.

Comment: You are not requesting the library for places. In your script src alter `&libraries=` to `&libraries=places`. This will ensure that library is included in the file you receive

Comment: ... which is why Google provides the `callback` parameter so that you can call any function **after** the API has loaded.

Comment: @Adiyta, it doesn't work even after adding &libraries=places

Comment: @Johnroiste You have a few typos throughout your code, if you fix that it should be fine

Comment: At one point you've written `PlaceServiceStatus.OK` instead of `PlacesServiceStatus.OK` at another point youve written `new google.mpas.Marker` instead of `new google.maps.Marker`. As long as you've constructed the URL properly, it should be fine once the typos are fixed

Comment: I have changed the typos but still not working. Maybe the URL is not right:                        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEY]&callback=initialize&libraries=places=&v=week"

Comment: @Aditya, I just removed the end of the URL &v=weekly and the markers are showing up now, thanks! I'm still getting a 'initialize is not a function error but it seems to be working! Thanks for your help!